# Captcha para Formidable (Formulário) - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, formulário, plugin, captcha

Boa tarde!

Estou precisando de um plugin de captcha no qual funcione juntamente com o Formidable.

No caso, o que já tem no Formidable só funciona em um formulário por página, e como estou precisando usar 2x na mesma página, não ta rolando.

Alguém pode indicar um que funcione dessa forma?

Answer (score 0):

Eu mesmo vou responder, caso alguém também passe pelo mesmo.

Após um tempinho de pesquisa, vi num artigo que usuários do Formidable Pro tem opção de marcar uma campo onde permite incluir mais de um captchas em uma mesma página.